# why does singular values of M equal to square roots of eigenvalues $M^TM$

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, data-mining

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), there is a rule to compute singular values

> The non-zero singular values of M (found on the diagonal entries of Σ)
>   are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of both $M^*M$ and $MM^*$.

for simplicity, let M is an m*n matrix of real values.

why does this rule apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = U\Sigma V^{*}.$ Then what is $M^*M$? Given that $\Sigma$ is diagonal, what can you say about the eigenvalues of $M^*M$?

Hint: Eigenvalues are invariant under ...